# Get value of bootstrap-tagsinput while on change event in jquery using bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, django-bootstrap3

I am using bootstrap3. I need to get value of tagsinput while on change event in jquery. I mentioned the belpow code

```
 <input type="text"  name="tag_name" id="tagchange" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput">
```

i am not able to get those value while on change event

```
 $('#tagchange').change(function(){
    alert($('#tagchange').val())
 });
```

[image]

Comment: try to use this onchange method  on-tag-removed,on-tag-add

Answer (score 5):

You should use one of tagsinput events. For example `itemAdded`

```
$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
    alert($('#tagchange').val());
});
```

See the [documentation](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/), at the bottom you have the event section.

Comment: I've also used `$('input').on('itemRemoved', function(event)` with it and get value on add and remove. Upvote for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this then.

```
$('#tagchange').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
   alert(event.item)
});
```

For more methods check this [Documentation](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```js
$("#tagchange").on("keyup", function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"  name="tag_name" id="tagchange" class="form-control" value="" data-role="tagsinput">
```

Or this way

`$("#tagchange").keyup(function() {
   alert($(this).val()); 
});`

Comment: Not like that.. I am trying to do with the above pic which i added.